# Static constants and methods in a Zend Framework model class

Tags: zend-framework, model, visibility

I have a Zend Framework model class like this

```
class UserModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users';
    protected $_primary = "id";

    const SEX_MALE = "male";
    const SEX_FEMALE = "female";

    const MIN_AGE = 13;

    public static function age(Zend_Date $bornDate) {

        $now = new Zend_Date(null, null, Zend_Locale::BROWSER);

        $diff = $now->sub($bornDate);

        $age = floor($diff->toValue() / 31556926);

        if ($age < 0) {

            throw new Zend_Date_Exception("invalid date");

        }

        return $age;

    }

}
```

It will have all the function to insert, remove or update records.

But when I try to access to the static function or to the static constant it says that it don't find the class.

How can I can make the class visible?

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Are you using autoloading ? if yes, do you use Zend_Loader_Autoloader ? what are the error/exception message and stack ?

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I try to access to the static constant and to the static function from a form. The error is simple this: Fatal error: Class 'UserModel' not found in /home/content/22/7907922/html/awatag20/library/Form/NewAwatag.php on line 62

Comment: The class that I want to load is in application/models. I tried with Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload("UserModel") but it still don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you use your classes and in this case a model class. I can only assume you have a file named UserModel.php. If you have such a file and you follow a default setup than you have it in your `application/models` folder. If that's what you have than the problem is simple. Rename the class to `Application_Model_UserModel`. You will, of course, have to call the class with this new name!

If you don't have a default setup then you probably are missing an include() for the file where the class is located.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the _Application_Model_UserModel_ the standard name? Zend Studio suggest me that name.

Comment: It seems it does not work. The file is in _application/models/UserModel.php_ and the class name is _Application_Models_UserModel_. It's that right?

Comment: The folder is named `models` (plural) but the class has to be `_Model_` (singular) and it is required for autoloader to work. Otherwise as I said you would have to `include()` the file manually